# nginx proxy to remote node.js express app in subdirectory

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, proxy

I am completely stuck with a situation where I want to have several node applications on one server. I get this working fine by having the applications running on different ports. I can access the applications by putting in the ip address with port.

I would like to proxy the applications from my nginx server by using different sub-directories like so:

```
my.domain

location /app1 {
  proxy_pass http://10.131.6.181:3001;
}
location /app2 {
  proxy_pass http://10.131.6.181:3002;
}
```

Doing this I had to move the all the express routes to /app1 for application1. This works but now I am stuck with the static files.

I can now access the application with http://10.131.6.181:3001/app1 which is great, but via http://my.domain/app1 the static files are not loaded.

The static files can be accessed directly http://10.131.6.181:3001/css but not via the proxy http://my.domain/css

Ideally I would like to have the applications on different ports without the sub-directory in the express routes but only sub-directories in the proxy. I tried to put my head through the wall for the last 5 hours but didn't achieve anything.

Now I would happy if can at least get the static files via the nginx proxy.

Comment: you might want to take a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/562756/how-to-remove-the-path-with-an-nginx-proxy-pass , maybe this helps

Comment: do i need to setup nginx on the node server as well? so i redirect from the webserver to the node server and the redirect again in a second nginx on the node server?

Comment: ah, i thought this was nginx, do you use apache?

Comment: yes... i use nginx on my webserver and thought i can proxy straight to the node server but it doesn't work.

Comment: i tested the 302 return but it didn't work.

Comment: then the post i linked to should help you, why would you need a second nginx?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124454/discussion-between-dennis-bauszus-and-johannes-merz).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An updated answer for anyone who needs:

instead of

```
location /app1 {
  proxy_pass http://10.131.6.181:3001/app1;
}
```

use

```
location /app1/ {
  proxy_pass http://10.131.6.181:3001/;
}
```

or if on local

```
location /app1/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
}
```

This is the correct way and this way you will not need to modify express. Express will receive only the part after /app1/

Comment: It is. Sorry for the late change. I wasn't able to look into this before.

Answer (score 2):

I finally worked it out after a google surge.

I added the directories to the nginx proxy_pass

```
my.domain

location /app1 {
  proxy_pass http://10.131.6.181:3001/app1;
}
location /app2 {
  proxy_pass http://10.131.6.181:3002/app2;
}
```

And I had to change the express applications to use the subdirectory

```
app.use('/app1', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/app1'', require('./routes'));
```

In the router I had to prefix all the redirects.

```
router.get('/logout', function (req, res) {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/app1/login');
});
```

The static files are called like so from html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/app1/css/style.css"/>
```

A bit of a pain to change all the redirects and static url. I am sure there is a smarter way by setting a global variable in my node-express app. If anybody knows an easier way please post...

Comment: Did you ever find a better way? I'm at the same crossroads. New to Nginx, could adjust my entire express app, hoping for a simple fix.