# How do I use Nginx docker as reverse proxy to route between two different containers?

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, docker-compose, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to use nginx docker image as a reverse proxy to route between 2 different containers based on the path. One container includes a static HTML file and another is a nodeJS application

This is my proxy.config file for nginx reverse proxy container

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app;
  }

  location /hello {
    proxy_pass http://node-app;
  }

}
```

The app container is a simple nginx container with a static HTML file that says HELLO WORLD and node-app container is the nodeJS application.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.1'

services: 
  app:
    build: app

  node-app:
    build: node-app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"

  proxy:
    build: nginx-reverseproxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
```

And this is the index.js for my nodeJS application

```js
const express = require('express');

// Constants
const PORT = 8080;

// App
const app = express();
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello world\n');
});

app.listen(PORT);
console.log(`Running on ${PORT}`);
```

Any ideas on what I'm getting wrong?

When I run this, it serves me the static page in the 'app' container when I GET on http://localhost. However, when I go to http://localhost/hello, it shows me 502 Bad Gateway.

But when I go to localhost:8080 the NodeJS response is served. I just need a way to route this to localhost/hello

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Hey, you checked the name of your container and if they are all the the came docker network, and if you can curl/wget from nginx container the node-app container.

Comment: But the issue most probably is you redirect on http without port so 80 while your service is in 8080, you should redicrect in your nginx conf to `proxy_pass http://node-app:8080;`

Comment: Otherwise you can set your node to run on the 80 port in the docker network, so chenge the `const PORT = 8080` to  'const PORT = 80' and then expose it to the outside on the 8080, so in the docker-compose, you change '8080:8080' to '8080:80' and then your nginx conf should work.

Comment: @Niradnik yeah did the same. Now it says "Cannot GET /hello" 
Turns out I'm able to do nslookup to node-app so DNS is registering it but it's not being mapped to the '/hello' route

Comment: hmm what did you try when you say "did the same" ?

Comment: @Niradnik ok so I changed the port to 80 and in docker compose exposed it to 8080 but now we're back to Bad Gateway. This is really confusing. But I think we're getting somewhere. Appreciate your help though.

Comment: but you also change it in the node config as well right ? try something like `docker exec -it proxy curl http://node-app`

Comment: maybe my comments are confusing.. You have 2 choices, if you keep the nginx conf as you wrote it 
`location /hello {
    proxy_pass http://node-app;
  }` 
then you need to change your node-app to have something running on the 80 port.
Otherwise you can keep the nodejs config so you will have something running on `8080` and then you say to nginx to look for `8080`, 
`location /hello {
    proxy_pass http://node-app:8080;
  }`

Comment: Ok so what I have currently in nginx.conf - 
    `location /hello { proxy_pass http://node-app; }`
And in my nodeJS config, I've set the app to listen to port 80 and in my docker-compose I've set port to "8080:80" 
And now when I run 
    `docker exec -it proxy curl http://node-app`
It gives me this error - starting container process caused "exec: \"curl\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: Okay try to run the same replacing `curl` by `wget`

Comment: and check also if you still get something on `localhost:8080` from your host

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I have the same issue. The Docker network is working fine, it's an issue with the reverse proxy.

Comment: Found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754435/nginx-proxy-to-remote-node-js-express-app-in-subdirectory